# My overloaded [] operator does not work for a pseudo 3D array

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I wrote a small demo which should implement the a pseudo `[][][] operator` for a three dimensional `std::vector`. The aim is to call the `[] operator` until just type T is returned. Unfortunately, the program seems to crash and the operator is called recursively.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class V1D : public std::vector<T>
{
private:
  int _iX = 0;
  int _iBeg = 0;

public:
  V1D(int x, int beg, std::vector<T> &buf)
    : _iX(x)
  {
    this->swap(buf);
    _iBeg = beg;
  }

  T& operator[] (int id) {
    return (*this)[id + _iBeg];
  }
};

template <class T>
class V2D : public std::vector<T>
{
private:
  int _iX = 0;
  int _iY = 0;
  int _iBeg = 0;

public:
  V2D(int x, int y)
    : _iX(x)
    , _iY(y)
  {
    this->resize(_iX*_iY);
  }

  V2D(int x, int y, int beg, std::vector<T> &buf)
    : _iX(x)
    , _iY(y)
  {
    this->swap(buf);
    _iBeg = beg;
  }

  V1D<T> operator[] (int id) {
    int iBeg = id*_iX;
    return V1D<T>(_iX, iBeg+_iBeg, *this);
  }
};

template <class T>
class V3D : public std::vector<T>
{
private:
  int _iX = 0;
  int _iY = 0;
  int _iZ = 0;

public:
  V3D() = default;
  V3D(int x, int y, int z) 
    : _iX(x)
    , _iY(y)
    , _iZ(z) 
  {
    this->resize(_iX*_iY*_iZ);
  }

  V2D<T> operator[] (int id) {
    int iBeg = id*_iY*_iZ;
    return V2D<T>(_iY, _iZ, iBeg, *this);
  }
};

int main()
{
    V3D<float> v3(3, 3, 3);
    float v = v3[1][1][0];
    v3[1][1][0] = 5;
    v = v3[1][1][0];
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Because you invoke it recursively. (*"return (*this)[id + _iBeg];"*).

Comment: What do you expect `return (*this)[id + _iBeg];` to do other than call your `operator[]` method?

Comment: Oh my gosh. got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think doing this->swap(buf) in V1D and V2D constructors (which likely should be private) is a good idea. If you think about it, V3D::operator[] will swap empty vector from a temporary (it is returning as the result) with whatever you have in your variable. So you loose the content. This design WILL NOT work. You likely need to return a pointer into vector's data wrapped in a helper class.

V1D and V2D should not and need not to hold/be a vector. They should wrap plain T pointer, possibly with inner sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You call `operator[]` recursively

```
T& operator[] (int id) {
    return (*this)[id + _iBeg];
}
```

should be

```
T& operator[] (int id) {
    return std::vector<T>::operator[](id + _iBeg);
}
```

Comment: I think if you just delete the operator it will just use the inherited one.

Comment: The program still crashes. There seems to be an additional bug somewhere :/

Comment: @dgrat, deleting operator? but you had an extended logic in your operator, you added `_iBeg` to the index.

Comment: Because I don't want to copy the array or elements. Guess the swap is the problem.

Comment: @dgrat, Yes, as @Tomek answered, the problem is the `swap` inside constructors, and more generally the design where `V1D` and `V2D` are also `std::vector` with their own buffers.

Comment: I don't really know to whom I should give the accept?

Comment: @dgrat, I propose you to edit the question, add that after you fixed operator you got another error, and accept Tomek's answer.